# Which Certificate do I need to buy for UWP?

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, certificate, ssl-certificate, code-signing

So my situation:

I built an Sideloaded UWP app with Visual Studio. Visual Studio can create an .pfx certificate that is temporary for 1 year. After that you have to recreate another certificate. The year for my certificate is almost over. Now I was thinking of buying such a certificate with more than 1 year of a lifetime.

Now my problem is that I absolutly don´t understand what I actually have to look for. When searching for certificates I find all kinds of SSL Certificates. Do I need SSL certificates for my case? Because it seems this is some web related certificate. Then there are EV OV DV, S/MIME Email Certificates and everything just does not seem right.

Code Signing OV is the closest I could find.

There also are alot of other different Code Signing certificates. Some list details like: "Authenticode, Office VBA, Java, Adobe Air, Mac / OSX, Android"

Some other just list the detail "Multiplatform" on like 5 different offers that all look the same and when you look into the description those informations are probably important: "32- und 64-Bit-Files like .exe, .cab, .dll, .ocx, .msi, .xpi, .xap and Kernel-Software" + "SHA-1".

Then there are CodeSignings like this "Microsoft Authenticode (Multi-Purpose)" with "SHA-2"

And this are just a few examples. There are alot offers and I understand neither of them. Just give me a working .pfx file.

Anyway

I was hoping that someone could help me understand on what I should be looking for if I want to have a certificate for my Sideloaded UWP app similar to the certificate that Visual Studio can create.

Answer (score 0):

You need a code signing certificate which can be bought from [digicert](https://www.digicert.com/code-signing/) for example. Please refer to the their [support page](https://www.digicert.com/code-signing/support/) for more information about how it works.

If you need a public certificate, you'll find a special offer on [this link](https://www.digicert.com/friends/sysdev/).